# Finite Cantor's Diagonal

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

Given a list of `N` integers, each with `N` digits, output a number which differs from the first number because of the first digit, the second number because of the second digit, etc.

#### Example

Given this list:

```
1234
4815
1623
4211
```

The number `2932`'s first digit is different from the first number's first digit, its second digit is different from the second number's second digit, etc. Therefore it would be a valid output.

#### Inputs

- You may take both the list and `N` as input, or only the list if you wish.
- Each integer in the list will necessarily have as many digits as the length of the list (`N`)
- Numbers will not have any leading zeroes
- The input list must contain numbers and not strings.
- You may take inputs as function arguments, through `STDIN`, or anything similar.
- You may assume that the list will not be longer than 10 elements (and no number in the list will be bigger than `2147483647`)

#### Outputs

- It is not sufficient that the output is not in the list. The digits must differ as explained above.
- You can use any digit selection strategy that respects the constraint of different digits.
- The number cannot have leading zeroes
- You may output the number through `STDOUT`, return it from a function, etc.

#### Test cases

```
Input:
12345678
23456789
34567890
45678901
56789012
67890123
78901234
89012345

Possible output: 24680246


Input:
1

Possible output: 2
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: So we have to convert the `STDIN` to integer before parsing?

Comment: @KennyLau input has to be numbers, if you language can parse digits directly you don't have to convert anything.

Comment: But `STDIN` is string by default...

Comment: Then convert the input string to a list of integers.

Comment: Can we output a list of digits?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ No, the output is an integer.

Comment: Can I answer in say, Retina, which doesn't have the concept of a number? (at least in the sense of it being different from a string in any meaningful way)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman If your language's natural representation of integers is strings then yes.

Comment: When you say the output cannot have leading zeroes, does that mean it must be the same length as the input, or can there be fewer digits as long as leading zeroes are not displayed?

Comment: @xnor there cannot be fewer digits

Comment: This is naturally best done in [DZZZZ](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DZZZZ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

1 byte saved thanks to Dennis.

```
DŒDḢỊ‘Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=RMWSROG4ouG7iuKAmOG4jA&input=&args=OTIzNDU2NzgsMjM0NTY3ODksMzQ1Njc4OTAsNDU2Nzg5MDEsNTY3ODkwMTIsNjc4OTAxMjMsNzg5MDEyMzQsODkwMTIzNDU)

#### Explanation

```
DŒDḢỊ‘Ḍ    Main link. Takes list as argument.
D          Convert each integer to decimal.
 ŒD        Get the diagonals.
   Ḣ       Get the first diagonal.
    Ị      Check if every digit <= 1.
     ‘     Increment every digit.
      Ḍ    Convert back to integer from decimal.
```

Converts each digit to `1`, except `0` and `1` becomes `2`.

Answer (score 8):

### CJam (<strike>15</strike> 14 bytes)

```
qN/ee{:=i2%)}%
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2Fee%7B%3A%3Di2%25)%7D%25&input=12345678%0A23456789%0A34567890%0A45678901%0A56789012%0A67890123%0A78901234%0A89012346)

Thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan) for a one-byte saving.

#### Dissection

```
qN/    e# Split input on newlines
ee{    e# Label each line with its index and map:
  :=i  e#   Get the character at the same index (i.e. diagonalise)
  2%)  e#   Compute (ASCII value mod 2) + 1
       e#   Maps 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
       e#     to 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
}%
```

Comment: @Adnan, that does work, thanks. Alternatively `i2%)` could be `49&)`, working directly with characters rather than ASCII codes.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```
lambda x,n:int(`x`[1::n+3])%(10**n/2)+10**n/9
```

*Thanks to @xnor for golfing off 2 bytes!*

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/B7wAft).

#### How it works

`` `x` `` yields a string representation of the list **x**.

For the first test case, this gives the *string*

```
[92345678, 23456789, 34567890, 45678901, 56789012, 67890123, 78901234, 89012345]
```

`[1::n+3]` retrieves every **(n + 3)**<sup>th</sup> character – where **n** is the length of **x** starting with the second one. Accounting **2** characters for `,`, we retrieve the first digit of the first number, the second digit of the second number, etc.

```
[92345678, 23456789, 34567890, 45678901, 56789012, 67890123, 78901234, 89012345]
 ^          ^          ^          ^          ^          ^          ^          ^
```

We now take the number modulo **10<sup>n</sup> ÷ 2** to map the first digit in the range **[0, 4]**.

For **93579135**, we get **93579135 % 50000000 = 43579135**.

Finally, we add **10<sup>n</sup> ÷ 9** to the last result, which increments – wrapping around from **9** to **0** – all digits by **1** (no carry) or **2** (with carry).

For **43579135**, we get **43579135 + 11111111 = 54690246**.

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
VXd9\QV!U
```

Takes only a column vector of integers as input. `N` is not provided.

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=VlhkOVxRViFV&input=WzIyMzQ1Njc4OzIzNDU2Nzg5OzM0NTY3ODkwOzQ1Njc4OTAxOzU2Nzg5MDEyOzY3ODkwMTIzOzc4OTAxMjM0Ozg5MDEyMzQ1XQ)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicity grab input as column vector of numbers
V   % Convert the input column vector into a 2D character array
Xd  % Grab the diagonal elements of the character array
9\  % Take the modulus of each ASCII code and 9
Q   % Add 1 to remove all zeros
V   % Convert the result to a string
!   % Transpose to yield a row vector of characters
U   % Convert back to an integer (as per the rules)
    % Implicitly display result
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh crud. It looks like it has a leading zero issue though when the first digit is `2`: http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=VlhkMTBcViFV&input=WzIyMzQ1Njc4OzIzNDU2Nzg5OzM0NTY3ODkwOzQ1Njc4OTAxOzU2Nzg5MDEyOzY3ODkwMTIzOzc4OTAxMjM0Ozg5MDEyMzQ1XQ

Comment: Maybe `VXd9\QV!U`

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of leading zero...

Comment: @LuisMendo Does it matter that they aren't unique? As long as they aren't the same value as the input it shouldn't matter.

Comment: You're totally right. I was thinking about it the wrong way

Comment: @LuisMendo Well together we were finally able to save that byte! Thanks!

Comment: Well, my contribution was to push you in the wrong direction so that you could solve it yourself :-D

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
jk.eh!ts@`b
```

Simple loop, change every digit to 1, except 1 becomes 2.

Comment: Nice usage of the implicit `Q` and `k`! You can save one byte with during the digit-transformation though: ``s.eh-12@`b``

Answer (score 3):

## Retina, <del>39</del> <del>38</del> 37

```
(?<=(.*¶)*)(?<-1>.)*(.).*¶
$2
T`d`121
```

Saved 1 byte thanks Martin!

Requires a trailing linefeed in the input.

Gets diagonals and translates 0 and 2-9 to 1 and 1 to 2.

The basic idea for getting the diagonals is to push a capture for each row above the current row and then consume a capture to match a character, then keep the next character.

[Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=KD88PSguKsK2KSopKD88LTE-LikqKC4pLirCtgokMgpUYGRgMTIx&input=MTIzNAo0ODE1CjE2MjMKNDIxMAo)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 93 bytes

```
String k(int n,int[]a){String s="";for(int i=0;i<n;)s+=(a[i]+s).charAt(i++)<57?9:1;return s;}
```

#### Ungolfed

```
String k(int n, int[] a) {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ) 
        s += (a[i] + s).charAt(i++) < 57 ? 9 : 1;
    return s;
}
```

#### Output

```
Input:
12345678
23456789
34567890
45678901
56789012
67890123
78901234
89012345

Output:
99991999

Input:
1234
4815
1623
4211

Output:
9999
```

Answer (score 3):

## J, <s>26</s> 22 bytes

```
1+1>:i.@#{"_1"."0@":"0
```

Similar approach to the others using the `<= 1` and `increment` method of the diagonal.

### Usage

Only requires the list of integers as an argument.

```
   f =: 1+1>:i.@#{"_1"."0@":"0
   f 1234 4815 1623 4211
2 1 1 2
   f 92345678 23456789 34567890 45678901 56789012 67890123 78901234 89012345
1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1
```

Comment: Sorry to break the 1 streak...

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 54 bytes

```
d,r=1,""
for n in input():r+=`1+-~n/d%9`;d*=10
print r
```

Comment: [Sounds familiar. `-~n`](/questions/78448?page=2#comment191822_78453)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 94 bytes

```java
int c(int[]d){int p=1,r=0,l=d.length,i=0;for(;i<l;p*=10)r+=(d[l-++i]/p%10==1?2:1)*p;return r;}
```

Pure numeric operations for the win! :)

#### Sample input/output:

```java
8            <-- size
12345678     <-- start of list
23456789
34567890
45678901
56789012
67890123
78901234
89012345     <-- end of list
21111211     <-- result from ungolfed code
21111211     <-- result from golfed code
```

#### Full program (with ungolfed code):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q79444 {
    int cantor_ungolfed(int[] data){
        int power = 1;
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            result += (((data[data.length-i-1]/power))%10==1? 2 : 1)*power;
            power *= 10;
        }
        return result;
    }
    int c(int[]d){int p=1,r=0,l=d.length,i=0;for(;i<l;p*=10)r+=(d[l-++i]/p%10==1?2:1)*p;return r;}
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] input = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            input[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(new Q79444().cantor_ungolfed(input));
        System.out.println(new Q79444().c(input));
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Reng v.3.3, 60 bytes

```
k1-#kaiír1ø          ~; !nb$<
1[å{$}k*$k1-#k)9(-#oa$;]o)ks^$
```

For Reng, that was rather simple. [Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/) Input is a space-separated list of numbers.

### 1: init

```
k1-#kaiír1ø
```

`k` is the number of inputs (number of numbers), and we decrement by 1 and restore for the loop stage. `aií` takes all input. `r` reverses the stack for the processing of input. `1ø` goes to the next line.

### 2: loop

```
1[å{$}k*$k1-#k)9(-#oa$;]o)ks^$
```

`1[` takes the top item off the stack and into a new stack. `å` splits it into digits. `{$}` pushes a code block containing the operation "drop"; this is repeated `k` times (`k*`) and the code block is dropped (`$`. `k1-#k` decrements `k`. `)9(` puts `9` at the STOS, and `-` subtracts TOS from the STOS. `#o` stores this number in `o`, and `a$;` drops all the members of the stack. `]` closes the parent stack. `o` puts `o` back at the top; this is our digit we're saving. `)` moves it to the bottom so that we can continue our looping. `s` usually checks for non-input (i.e., equality to `-1`), but we can use it to break out of our loop when `k == -1`. So `s^` goes up when `k == -1`. `$` drops `k` from the stack, and our loop begins again.

### 3: final

```
                     ~; !nb$<
```

`<` directs the pointer left, and `$` drops `k` from the stack. `b` is a leftway mirror, so we enter through it, but it bounce back when hitting `;`, a stack-condition mirror. `!n` prints a digit if and only if we're going left. `~` ends the program when we're done printing.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 21 bytes

```
$><<$_[$.-1].hex%2+1
```

A full program. Run with the `-n` flag. Uses the following mapping: `n -> n%2+1`.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 18 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with the input lines on STDIN. Output is 1 except 2 when the diagonal is 1

`cantor.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
pos=$.;$_=/1\G/+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
s.e|-\1@bk\2`M
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.e|-%5C1%40bk%5C2%60M&input=12345678%2C23456789%2C34567890%2C45678901%2C56789012%2C67890123%2C78901234%2C89012345&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 37 bytes

```
f@(9&-@"."0@((>:@#*i.@#){f=:[:,":"0))
```

Can probably be golfed, but I forgot if there was a command for "diagonals".

Comment: I've seen it used before, Martin used the anti-diagonals [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77220/31625).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yeah, that's close. I'm still looking, but there might not be.

Comment: This seems to produce a leading zero if the diagonal begins with a 9.

Comment: You can create the digits table if you take the input `n` using `<list> (#:~#&10) <n>`. The first diagonal can be found with `(< 0 1) |: <list>` where `(< 0 1)` is a box for the axes to select, using both, with `|:`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 52 bytes

```
FromDigits[Mod[#,2]+1&/@Diagonal[IntegerDigits/@#]]&
```

This follows the approach of Peter Taylor and others (without using Ascii codes).

Example

```
FromDigits[Mod[#,2]+1&/@Diagonal[IntegerDigits/@ #]]&[{1234,4815,1623,4211}]
```

> 2112

Answer (score 1):

## ClojureScript, 58 chars

```
#(int(apply str(map-indexed(fn[i x](- 9(get(str x)i)))%)))
```

Type requirements made this a little longer than necessary, and `map-indexed` being so many chars didn't help.

Often my submissions are valid Clojure as well, but this is using some of ClojureScript's leakiness with JavaScript.  Subtraction of a number and string coerces the string to a number--that is, `(- 9 "5")` equals `4`.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP, 46/41/40 bytes**

```
while($a=$argv[++$i])echo($b=9-$a[$i-1])?$b:1;

while($a=$argv[++$i])echo$a[$i-1]==7?6:7;

while($a=$argv[++$i])echo($a[$i-1]%2)+1;
```

Various digit selectors for comparison. I thought "9-digit" would be shortest, but the special case needed to keep a zero out of the first digit overwhelms it.

Fed from CLI arguments:

```
php -r "while($a=$argv[++$i])echo($b=9-$a[$i-1])?$b:1;" 12345678 23456789 34567890 45678901 56789012 67890123 78901234 89012345
86421864
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 41

The %9+1 trick is borrowed from Suever's answer. For once, `.reduce` beats `.map`. Note, the `+=` operator is used to avoid parentheses.

```
a=>+a.reduce((t,n,d)=>t+=(n+t)[d]%9+1,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 49 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 6.125 bytes

```
vfÞ/ċ›ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJhPSIsIiIsInZmw54vxIvigLrhuYUiLCIiLCIxMjM0XG40ODE1XG4xNjIzXG40MjExIl0=)

Port of Jelly